# Online Java Book

Tags: java

Is there an online Java book like *Dive into Python* for learning Python?

Other resources online besides the standard Java documentation (which is awesome but almost too technical)
.

Comment: i don't think this question should be tagged with python keyword.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Definitely "[Thinking in Java](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/)" by Bruce Eckel.

Answer (score 4):

Hard to tell if you meant this by "standard online documentation" but the [Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/) is excellent and what many of us old-timers started with.

Answer (score 0):

When I was learning Java, I constantly found myself going back to this site: [Java Programming Notes](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/index.html)

Very thorough yet concise and easy to read.